# How to create correct `WebDriverwait` statement in python with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999661/force-selenium-to-pause-and-wait-for-a-field-to-be-available) I created a similar expression to check for an element:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until((EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search in your collabs']")))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
...
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until((EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search in your collabs']")))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

But according to the example and the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) that should be a correct expression! So why does it still fail (`python2.7`)?

Comment: The syntax is not correct, there's an unexpected parenthese just after `until(`. Move it before `By.XPATH`.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @FlorentB. Why not post the solution as answer so everybody knows the issue is solved?

Comment: @Würgspaß, feel to post the answer. SO is not a bug-tracker for SO, so it would probably be more useful to fix the other/original post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Syntax issue. See first comment by *Florent B.*